# Stable base loci and flips

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, birational-geometry, divisors, flips-flops

Let $D_1,D_2$ be two effective divisors on o normal and $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial projective variety $X$ of Picard rank two. Assume that $D_1$ is semi-ample and that it induces a small-comtraction $f_{D_1}:X\rightarrow Z$ contracting an irreducible subvariety $R\subset X$ of codimension at least two. Furthermore assume that there exists the flip $\phi:X\dashrightarrow X^{+}$ of $f_{D_1}$.

Finally, assume that the stable base locus of $D_2$ is contained in $R$, and let $D_2^{+}\subset X^{+}$ be the strict transform of $D_2$ via $\phi$.

Is then $D_2^{+}$ semi-ample on $X^{+}$ ?